# How do I update if exist and insert if not using mongoengine (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

It is really absurd how mongoengine has such arcane documentation. I am trying to do a simple (update if exists query) based on a few columns/fields. What I mean by that is

```
if fieldA has valueA and 
   fieldB has valueB and 
   fieldC has valueC 
then
update fieldD with newValueD, 
       fieldE with newValueE
```

I could do it in the method mentioned below but I am pretty sure there is a really simple upsert syntax where if I mention the fields and values then it matches it across the collection, updates if they match and inserts if they don't

```
def __generateRemoteData(data):
    """
    Utils function to add remote data to Mongo

    """
    for datum in data:
        query = RemoteGraph.objects(
            Q(fieldA=datum.get('fieldA')) and
            Q(fieldB=datum.get('fieldB')) and
            Q(fieldC=datum.get('fieldC')) and
            Q(fieldD=datum.get('fieldD')) and
            Q(fieldE=datum.get('fieldE')) and
            Q(date=datum.get('date'))
        )
        if not query:
            RemoteGraph(
                fieldA=datum.get('fieldA'),
                fieldB=datum.get('fieldB'),
                fieldC=datum.get('fieldC'),
                fieldD=datum.get('fieldD'),
                fieldE=datum.get('fieldE'),
                date=datum.get('date'),
                fieldF=datum.get('fieldF'),
                fieldG=datum.get('fieldG'),
            ).save()
        else:
            query.update(
                set__fieldF=datum.get('fieldF'),
                set__fieldG=datum.get('fieldG'),
            )
```

Looking for a more pythonic way to do this.

I have looked into `upsert`, `insert`, `modify`, `save`, `update`, `update_one`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Q() combines only with bitwise operators. And the meaning of Q is in combining `&` and `|` operators. Detailed [here](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#advanced-queries)

There is a special option `upsert=True` of the [`QuerySet::update`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.update) method. Upsert – force an insertion of a new document if `RemoteGraph.objects(a=val_a, b=val_b, c=val_c, date=date)` founds no one document.

```py
RemoteGraph.objects(
    a=val_a, b=val_b, c=val_c, date=date
).update(
    a=val_a, b=val_b, c=val_c, date=date
)
```

Also there are `[QuerySet::modify][3]` and [`QuerySet::update_one`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.update_one) method, they could upsert new document too, but unlike of [`QuerySet::update`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.update), they will update only first document from `QuerySet`.

And finally there is a [`QuerySet::upsert_one`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.upsert_one). The name says it all. One noticeable distinction it raises an Exception if the QuerySet contains more than one document. Actually `QuerySet::update_one` and `QuerySet::upsert_one` are small wrappers over `QuerySet::update`